# Can I query from 2 tables like this?

Tags: android, sqlite

Can I query from 2 tables like this?

```
public Cursor getSen_List(long id_thsen ) {
    String strTmp = "select "
        +SENS_TABLE+"."+KEY_SEN_ID+","
        +SENS_TABLE+"."+KEY_SEN_ID_TH_SEN+","
        +SENS_TABLE+"."+KEY_SEN_ID_LANG+","
        +SENS_TABLE+"."+KEY_SEN+","
        +SENS_TABLE+"."+KEY_SEN_READING+","    
        +LANGS_TABLE+"."+KEY_LANG
        +" from "+SENS_TABLE+ ","+LANGS_TABLE
        +" where "+SENS_TABLE+"."+KEY_SEN_ID_TH_SEN + "=" + id_thsen+ " and " 
        +SENS_TABLE+"."+KEY_LANG+"=  " +("select"
                                    +LANGS_TABLE+"."+KEY_LANG
                                    +"from"+LANGS_TABLE
                                    +"where"+LANGS_TABLE+"."+KEY_ACT+"=1");


                    return db.rawQuery(strTmp,null);}
```

This is my logcat

```
02-11 02:45:02.814: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-11 02:45:02.814: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.proj/com.android.proj.Sens_Show}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Sentences.lang: , while compiling: select Sentences._id,Sentences.id_thsen,Sentences.id_lang,Sentences.sen,Sentences.reading,Languages.lang from Sentences,Languages where Sentences.id_thsen=1 and Sentences.lang=  (select Languages.lang from Languages where Languages.active_status=1)
02-11 02:45:02.814: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
02-11 02:45:02.814: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
02-11 02:45:02.814: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
02-11 02:45:02.814: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
02-11 02:45:02.814: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-11 02:45:02.814: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-11 02:45:02.814: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-11 02:45:02.814: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-11 02:45:02.814: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-11 02:45:02.814: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-11 02:45:02.814: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-11 02:45:02.814: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-11 02:45:02.814: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Sentences.lang: , while compiling: select Sentences._id,Sentences.id_thsen,Sentences.id_lang,Sentences.sen,Sentences.reading,Languages.lang from Sentences,Languages where Sentences.id_thsen=1 and Sentences.lang=  (select Languages.lang from Languages where Languages.active_status=1)
02-11 02:45:02.814: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
02-11 02:45:02.814: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:91)
02-11 02:45:02.814: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:64)
02-11 02:45:02.814: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:80)
02-11 02:45:02.814: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:46)
02-11 02:45:02.814: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:42)
02-11 02:45:02.814: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1345)
02-11 02:45:02.814: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1315)
02-11 02:45:02.814: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625):     at com.android.proj.DBAdapter.getSen_List(DBAdapter.java:881)
02-11 02:45:02.814: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625):     at com.android.proj.Sens_Show.listData(Sens_Show.java:89)
02-11 02:45:02.814: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625):     at com.android.proj.Sens_Show.onCreate(Sens_Show.java:64)
02-11 02:45:02.814: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-11 02:45:02.814: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
02-11 02:45:02.814: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(625):     ... 11 more
```

sentence table

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_7 =
    " create table " + SENS_TABLE +
    " (_id integer primary key autoincrement," +
    " id_thsen integer REFERENCES Thai_sentences(_id)," +
    " id_lang integer REFERENCES Languages(_id)," +
    " sen text not null," +
    " reading text not null);";
```

language table`

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_3 =
    " create table " + LANGS_TABLE +
    " (_id integer primary key autoincrement," +
    " lang text not null," +
    " active_status integer not null);";
```

---

correct language but occur 5 time like amount of languages`

```
public Cursor getSen_List(long id_thsen ) {
    String strTmp = "select "
        +SENS_TABLE+"."+KEY_SEN_ID+","
        +SENS_TABLE+"."+KEY_SEN_ID_TH_SEN+","
        +SENS_TABLE+"."+KEY_SEN_ID_LANG+","
        +SENS_TABLE+"."+KEY_SEN+","
        +SENS_TABLE+"."+KEY_SEN_READING+","    
        +LANGS_TABLE+"."+KEY_LANG
        +" from "+SENS_TABLE+ ","+LANGS_TABLE
        +" where "+SENS_TABLE+"."+KEY_SEN_ID_TH_SEN + "=" + id_thsen+ " and " 
        +SENS_TABLE+"."+KEY_LANG_ID+"=  " +("(select "
                                    +LANGS_TABLE+"."+KEY_LANG_ID
                                    +" from "+LANGS_TABLE
                                    +" where "+LANGS_TABLE+"."+KEY_ACT+"=1)");


                    return db.rawQuery(strTmp,null);}
```

Comment: force close....I think maybe because of little mistake but I can't find could you please help...

Comment: It would be easier to help if you included the actual SQL string passed to rawQuery.

Comment: @grantnz How can you show me some example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need spaces around `select`, `from` and `where` in your subquery. You probably should enclose that subquery in `()` as well.

```
public Cursor getSen_List(long id_thsen ) {
    String strTmp = "select "
        +SENS_TABLE+"."+KEY_SEN_ID+","
        +SENS_TABLE+"."+KEY_SEN_ID_TH_SEN+","
        +SENS_TABLE+"."+KEY_SEN_ID_LANG+","
        +SENS_TABLE+"."+KEY_SEN+","
        +SENS_TABLE+"."+KEY_SEN_READING+","    
        +LANGS_TABLE+"."+KEY_LANG
        +" from "+SENS_TABLE+ ","+LANGS_TABLE
        +" where "+SENS_TABLE+"."+KEY_SEN_ID_TH_SEN + "=" + id_thsen+ " and " 
        +SENS_TABLE+"."+KEY_LANG+"=  " +("(select "
                                    +LANGS_TABLE+"."+KEY_LANG
                                    +" from "+LANGS_TABLE
                                    +" where "+LANGS_TABLE+"."+KEY_ACT+"=1)");


                    return db.rawQuery(strTmp,null);}
```

**EDIT:**

now you've posted the log you can see this line

`Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Sentences.lang:`

which points to the error. There is no column lang in the Sentences table

Comment: Can you post the content of strTmp (logcat or debug) to see what the query looks like right before it's executed?

Comment: @praew_z edited my answer. One of the referenced column does not exist in the table

Comment: please see my edit , I don't call Sentences.lang why logcat show like this?

Comment: logcat doesn't lie :) You have this in your query `SENS_TABLE+"."+KEY_LANG` which is `Sentences.lang` at runtime

Comment: sorry again @Damp Now I can call data in sentence table which come from only English language but in my languages table have 5 language so the sentence show the same 5 time (only english language) can you help me to make it show 1 time? please see my edit

Comment: add a limit to your query `limit 1`

Comment: At the very and of your query, after your where clauses

Comment: Oh Damp it show only 1 time but I try to set active language to use English and German this time it show only English Is it because I set "limit 1"?

Comment: Do you have a field in the Language table the tells you what language it is?  Do you have something in the code that tells you what language you need?  In your query add a filter (WHERE) clause to only get the language you need:  WHERE Table.LanguageType = CodeLanguageSelected

Comment: @Leslie I already have all of you ask you can see sentence table and language table in my question :) field lang mean name of language

Comment: @praew_z - Sorry the only WHERE filtering I see is WHERE KEY_LANG = (LANGS_TABLE.KEY_LANG WHERE KEY_ACT = 1) Does KEY_ACT mean the specific language you are looking for?  If the problem is that you are getting 5 DUPLICATE rows you can just add DISTINCT to your SELECT clause

Comment: @Leslie KEY_ACT mean active language (which active = 1 when people choose to show this language sentence and people can choose more than 1 language because it come from check box function) ,, And could you please tell me how to  DISTINCT to my SELECT clause

Comment: @praew_z at this point I think your question has been largely answered and I suggest you go and read though one of the numerous sql/mysql/sqlite tutorials out there. Concepts such as DISTINCT and LIMIT should probably be familiar to you before you start doing any serious DB development on Android.